# first 20 samples outputting `_id`, and `text`

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The following code outputs 20 **random** data samples of `_id`, and `text` from my collection

```
db.collection.aggregate({$sample: {size: 20}}, {$project: {"_id": 1,"text": 1}})
```

However, instead of 20 random samples, I want the `_id`, and `text` of the first 20 samples from my collection (**non-random**).

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `aggregate`:

```
db.movies.aggregate([{$project: {"text": 1}}, {$limit:20}])
```

With `find`:

```
db.movies.find({}, {"text": 1}).limit(20)
```